# Get a static java method to return highest variable value

Tags: java, oop, object, methods, static

In my program I declared a static variable:

```
private static int nextID = 0;
```

Which is used in my constructor

```
Vehicle() {

  idNum = nextID++

 }
```

Basically, what this is doing is ensuring that every time I make a new Vehicle object, it will have a unique identification number.  Now I want to make a static method that would return the highest IDnumber used so far. How would I do that?

Comment: You already have `nextID`.

Comment: `public static int getNextId() { return nextID; } `

Answer (score 5):

You can just return the current value of `nextID`...

Note however that your class is not thread safe. In other words if there are two different objects created at the same time they can both get the same "unique" id.
In order to prevent this you need some sort of locking.

```
private static int nextID = 0;
private static Object lockObj = new Object();

public static int highestID()
{
    synchronized(lockObj)
    {
        return nextID-1;
    }
}

public Vehicle() {
    synchronized(lockObj)
    {
        idNum = nextID++;
    }
}
```

Comment: This assumes that the class *needs* to be thread-safe.  If it doesn't, then the synchronization, etc is unnecessary, and it would be better to leave it out.

Comment: Nah, `volatile` will do the job.

Answer (score 2):

You pretty well answered the question yourself. Since your `nextID` variable is ever increasing each time an object is created, any time you grab the value of that variable, it is always the highest. All you need, as you've said, is to create a static method that returns the current value of `nextID`. Simply:

```
public static int getNextID(){
    return nextID;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Figured it out!

```
Public static int highestID() {

   return nextID;
 }
```